# How do you accept a text file in a method?

Tags: java, file, methods, call

What I'm trying to do is code a method that takes any kind of text input like

```
"words.text"
```

What I imagined it would look like would be

```
public static wordcount(File afile){....}
```

I want the method to be called such as

```
wordcount("words.txt");
```

I tried looking for the answer but couldn't find it. How do I do this?

Comment: Overload your method to accept a `String` and delegate to the other implementation taking a `File`.

Comment: @Zer0megAlpha You also need **return type**. For example, using `void`: `public static void wordcount(){....}`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the method with the following signature

```
public static void wordCount(String fileName){...}
```

Then inside the mthod use the string to make a File object.

```
public static void wordCount(String fileName){
    File aFile = new File(fileName);
}
```